# Kate - show all whitespace

Tags: kubuntu, kate

I am using kubuntu and would like for kate to show me all whitespace.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

- Click **Settings** > **Configure Kate...** to bring up the Configure dialog.
- Click **Editor Component** > **Appearance**.
- In the **Whitespace Highlighting** section, check **Highlight tabulators** and **Highlight trailing spaces**.
- In the **Advanced** section, check **Show indentation lines**.
- Click **OK**.

It seems one cannot highlight leading spaces.

Comment: Besides that also colors may need to be adjusted in: Configure Kate... > Editor Component > Fonts & Colors. At "Colors" tab in "Text Decoration" section.